# Problema al obtener información del usuario

Tags: javascript

Estoy usando una API de instagram, y estoy tratando de obtener la información de cualquier usuario para saber si su perfil es público o privado, ya que si es privado no se le hará mención, pero si es público se usará para X fines.

Intenté hacer un fetch de esta url `https://www.instagram.com/therock/?__a=1`, siendo "therock" una variable. Como no me daba resultado intenté hacerlo con XMLHttpRequest, pero me da un problema con el CORS.

```
let name = prompt('Escribe el nombre de usuario');
let oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open('GET', `https://www.instagram.com/${name}/?__a=1`, true);
    oReq.send();
    if(oReq.status == 200){
       console.log(req.responseText);
    }
```

Por más que lea la docu de XMLHttpRequest no consigo saber cómo hacer una cabecera con 'no-cors' para que no entre en conflicto.

¿Cómo podría obtener dicho json para trabajar con el con js?

---

**[EDIT]**

He cambiado la forma de INTENTAR obtener la información que necesito:

```
let name = prompt('Escribe el nombre de usuario');
let url = `http://instagram.com/${name}/?__a=1`;
let instagramPage = fileGetsContent(url);
//llamo a la funcion fileGetsContent, y mando la url como parametro
```

función fileGetsContent:

```
function fileGetsContent(url){
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    xhr.send();
    console.log(xhr);
}
```

Intenté poner Access-Control-Allow-Origin en *, para ver si podía obtener algo. Pero nada. Me devuelve un XHR vacío completamente.

[image: XML vacío]

Comment: La única solución es crear un `proxy pass` en tu backend para evitar el problema de CORS: Instagram no soporta CORS y tu navegador no te dejará hacer peticiones a ese dominio

Comment: Edito con algo mas de información. Porque me piden hacerlo de alguna manera, sin dicho proxy...